# How to handle exception created by an unmanaged code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, unmanagedresources

In my code i am running an exe file through a process call.
How to handle exception generated by the exe file.
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the exe file is unmanaged, you can't catch exceptions that it throws.

What you can do, is check its error code once the process exits. To do that use the `Process` class to launch the exe. It has a property that gives you the exit code.

If the exe was a managed assembly, you would have been able to run it in a separate AppDomain, and catch the exception it threw.

Comment: But i am not running any assembly, it's just an exe file (lets us say executable file of a c program).

Comment: So the process exit code is what you've got. A C program doesn't even have exceptions...

Comment: Suppose a C program has code "int a = b / 0;". So at run time it is creating an exception and showing an message box saying "Progam.exe has encountered a problem, do you want to send the report to microsoft", with "Send", "Don't send" button.